# Assign EXEC() in a variable in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I want assign result of `exec` command in variable named `@result` in below query:

```
DECLARE
     @SQL NVARCHAR(200),
     @FID NVARCHAR(4) = 'F',
     @RESULT FLOAT;

SET @SQL = 'F+1+2.5+1';

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, @FID, 3);

SELECT @SQL
```

I write this but not work:

```
set @result = EXEC('SELECT ' + @SQL)
```

Comment: Using T-SQL to evaluate arbitrary mathematical expressions is probably a *very* bad idea. There almost certainly has to be a better tool/technology to use somewhere between your users and this database system where it would be time better spent implementing this, with richer ways of representing expressions, etc, rather than doing it via text manipulation here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign the value of a variable in inside a "dynamic" (deferred) statement then you need to pass that variable, as a parameter, to your dynamic SQL. This is one reason why using `EXEC (@SQL)` is a bad idea, because you *cannot* parametrise it. Use `sys.sp_executesql`.

```sql
DECLARE @MyVariable int;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql
  N'SET @MyVariable = 1;',
  N'@MyVariable int OUTPUT',
  @MyVariable = @MyVariable OUTPUT;

PRINT @MyVariable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code translated to proper SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
     @SQL NVARCHAR(200),
     @FID INT,
     @RESULT FLOAT;

SET @SQL = 'SET @RESULT = @FID+1+2.5+1';

-- Set your parameters
SET @FID = 3

-- Execute
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@RESULT FLOAT OUTPUT, @FID INT'
,   @RESULT = @RESULT OUTPUT, @FID = @FID

-- Check results
SELECT  @RESULT
```

You can use parameters in dynamic sql, as long as you use SP_EXECUTESQL and pass them around according to the above code.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 for docs on the SP_EXECUTESQL